# How to parse through a mpeg file efficiently?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

Here, I am reloading the mpeg file each time to play a segment out of it.

I would rather step through one loaded file but I can't seem to establish a file pointer that is consistent in positioning ... this following approach is the best I can do.

What am I missing to effectively step through only one file?  thx

```
float offset[26] =  { 2.1,  3.1,  4.0,  5.0,  5.5,
                      6.5,  7.8,  8.8, 10.0, 10.7,
                     11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.3,
                     16.1, 17.2, 17.9, 18.9, 19.7,
                     20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 25.3 }; //fileOffset for voice segments


for (int i = 25; i > -1 ; i--) {
    player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
    player.numberOfLoops = 0; 

    [player playAtTime: player.deviceCurrentTime - offset[i]];

    sleep(1);//one second duration
    [player stop];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make use of the [- audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerDelegateProtocolReference/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/AVAudioPlayerDelegate/audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:successfully:) `AVAudioPlayerDelegate` method to find out when the snippet has finished playing, and then seek to the next position, avoiding the need to recreate the variable and reload the audio file each time.

```
@property (nonatomic) float indexOfLastOffset;
@property (nonatomic) float offsets[16]; 

- (void)viewDidLoad:(BOOL)animated {
    self.indexOfLastOffset = 25;
    self.offsets = { 2.1,  3.1,  4.0,  5.0,  5.5,
                  6.5,  7.8,  8.8, 10.0, 10.7,
                 11.5, 12.5, 13.5, 14.5, 15.3,
                 16.1, 17.2, 17.9, 18.9, 19.7,
                 20.5, 21.5, 22.5, 23.5, 24.5, 25.3 };

    AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
    player.numberOfLoops = 0; 
    player.delegate = self;
    [self player:player playWithOffsetIndex:self.indexOfLastOffset];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)player:(AVAudioPlayer *)player playWithOffsetIndex:(NSUInteger)offsetIdx {
    [player playAtTime:player.deviceCurrentTime - offsets[offsetIdx]];
}

- (void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:(AVAudioPlayer *)player
                       successfully:(BOOL)flag {
    if (flag && indexOfLastOffset >= 0) {
        [self player:player playWithOffsetIdx:self.indexOfLastOffset - 1];
        self.indexOfLastOffset -= 1;
    }
    else {
        [player stop];
    }
}
```